# How can I test a class that extends another class in PHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am new to PHPUnit, and I am currently trying to test a function that authenticates a user on the system. The function is called `authenticate()` and is located inside the `Account` class.

**Test**

```
public function passwordAreNotTheSame_Test()
{
    require 'login/app/models/Account.php';
    require 'login/app/controllers/Pages.php';
    require 'login/lib/Controller.php';

    $pages = new Pages();
    $account = new Account($pages);
    $username = "test_name";
    $password = "test_password";
    $cpassword = "invalid_password";
    $email = "email@test.com";
    $Expected = "Passwords do not match!";
    $Received = $account->register($username, $password, $cpassword, $email);
    
    $this->assertEquals($Expected, $Received);
}
```

However, my issue is that the constructor in the `Account` class also requires a controller called `Pages`. My issue is that the class `Pages,` located in the file `Pages.php` extends the class `Controller`. Like this:

```
class Pages extends Controller {
    // some code
}
```

So when I run my test, I get the following issue.

> Error : Class "Controller" not found
> C:\xampp\htdocs\apex-management\login\app\controllers\Pages.php:3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\apex-management\tests\Unit\RegisterAccountTests.php:13
> Time: 00:00.019, Memory: 8.00 MB
>
> ERRORS! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1. Process finished with exit
> code 2

How could I make this test work? I want to learn how to use PHPUnit, but I've found no documentation online for that type of issue.

Comment: check where is `Controller` class he can't find it and require the right path for it.

Comment: You're not properly requiring the file containing the `Controller` class. If you don't have an autoloader of some kind set up, you should be doing the `require` statement in the `Pages` code file.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using, and what command are you using to run the tests? Laravel comes with testing already set up and the Controller should be able to  be autoloaded without needing an explicit require.

Answer (score 0):

In php oop, it is supporing 'extends' keyword. Here is the example for that

```
<?php
class parent{
   //parent class definition
}

class child extends parent{
   //child class declarations
}

?>
```